# rich:fileUpload is not working in jboss-6.0.0.Final

Tags: jboss, richfaces, seam, jboss6.x

I migrated to Jboss AS jboss-6.0.0.Final and richfaces 3.3.3. In this version `<rich:fileUpload/>` is not working. The upload action is running for a long time which leads browser to throw a warning message. And also after selecting a file the other scripts in the page are not running. How to resolve this?

Comment: Which version of seam are you using? Also, try to use s:fileUpload and see if that works, before you try rich:fileUpload

Comment: Looks like you have JavaScript errors on page. Please specify it in the question. You can get error text from your browser (IE - click left bottom yellow triangle, firefox - use firebug, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>createTempFiles</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
```

To the Seam multipart filter in web.xml.  Not sure why, but using the Seam setting in components.xml for this doesn't necessarily work as advertised.
The param-value will be true/false based on how you're collecting the upload; as a file or as data.